# Firefox Custom Toolbar Button

Tags: firefox, touch, toolbar

I am trying to create a firefox toolbar button which when clicked calls (or invokes) TapTip.exe which is the Touch Keyboard for my Windows Tablet. I've tried following this tutorial (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Toolbars/Custom_toolbar_button) to get my button to work but no luck so far. Is there anyway I can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to due this by using a addon named Custom Buttons for Firefox then I found a Launch IE button which I modified to call TapTip.exe instead of IE